# the result weka j48 classifyinstance is not correct

Tags: machine-learning, weka, j48

I already build a tree to classify the instance. In my tree, there are 14 attributes. Each attribute is discretize by supervised discrete. When I created a new instance, I put the value in this instance and classify it in my tree, and I found the result is wrong. So I debug my program, and I found the value of the instance is not divided into the interval correctly. For example:
value of the instance:0.26879699248120303 is divided into '(-inf-0]'.

Why?

Comment: Improve your question to get quick and good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.I didn't discretize the instance that was to be tested so that the weka didn't know the format of my instance.add the following code:
`discretize.input(instance);//discretize is a filter
instance = discretize.output();`